# Integration formula proof

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

To get formula we can use integration by parts

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int \sin^n(x)\,dx \\\\
&=- \int \sin^{n-1}xd(\cos x)\,dx\\\\
& =-\cos x\sin^{n-1}x+(n-1)\int \sin^{n-2}x\cos^2(x) \,dx\\\\
&  = -\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}x + (n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_n .
\end{align}$$

I don't understand where we get $(- (n-1)I_n) $, and lose $\cos^2x$.

Dyakuyu!==Thank you!=)

Comment: Replace $\cos^2(x)$ with $1-\sin^2(x)$ withing your last integral in the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that

$$\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$$

and therefore

$$\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^2(x)=\sin^{n-2}(x)-\sin^n(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use $\cos^2x =1-\sin^2 x$ in the integral.